# Run Golang exec on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I'm developing tools in Golang that should run on AWS-Lambda in production. For developing and debuging/maintenance convenient I writing the tools as CLI tools. This way I or any of my teammates can develop the tools without dependencies with AWS-Lambda env.

My goal is to integrate these tools with the AWS-lambda environment with the minimum changes of the original code (the CLI-tools).

I'm thinking of two options:

1. Write a wapper for AWS-lambda that using [exec command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) to run the tools.
2. Export the core-code of the tool to a shared function.

The first option is more convenient and straightforward.

I'm wondering what is the impact of the [exec commnad](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) on the performance on low-price servers like AWS-lambda?

Comment: I do not think there should be performance issues in running the exec command on AWS-Lambda as long as you provision the right memory and get the proportional V-CPUs. For security reasons it is not advisable to spawn child processes or use exec commands in Serverless. Ex: a malicious package might inject bitcoin mining code to be executed as a child process.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/open-source/) or [AWS Serverless SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to run and test AWS Lambda code locally, don't necessarily need to use for deployments etc.. Both are compatible with Golang. They are easy to use and setup. These frameworks will help avoid overhead of creating wrappers to run code locally.